# Unable to connect to SharePoint online in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: sharepoint-online, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to debug a SharePoint App in Visual Studio.

When I click "start"  to debug, the normal "connect to sharepoint" window pops up, which I put the username and password in. Except when I enter the password, it logs into the site IN THE LOGIN DIALOG. It does not log my Visual studio in, and when I close it it asks me to go offline.

The exact same solution works on a different computer.
I am using Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: What happen when you ping SPO site from your computer?

Answer (score 0):

In Internet Explorer click on Option --> Compatibility Settings and then add your site. Then try again.

Answer (score 0):

It problem was due to the system clock being incorrect. once I corrected it. it worked.

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question.

Comment: @waqassarwarmcse this looks very much like an answer to me